# Tests not being convered by 2to3 in setup.py?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, setup.py, python-2to3

I have a setup.py that needs to support both Python 2 and 3.

The code currently works and is installable in Python 2.x

If I add the `use_2to3 = True` clause to my setup.py, then the module can be *installed* in Python 3, however, doing a:

```
python setup.py test
```

Causes a failure as one of the tests uses the StringIO class, and the import line goofs in Python 3 (it's currently `from StringIO import StringIO`, where in Python3 it should be `from io import StringIO`

I thought though that once you add the use_2to3 keyword all tests (including unittests) were processed by 2to3 before being tested.

What am I missing?  In case it helps, the bulk of my setup.py looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='myproject',
    version='1.0',
    description='My Cool project',
    classifiers = [
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
    ],

    py_modules=['mymodule'],
    test_suite='test_mymodule',
    zip_safe=False,
    use_2to3 = True,
)
```

Edit: the reason I feel as though 2to3 isn't getting run on a `python setup.py test` is that it blows up & the bottom of the stacktrace reads:

```
File "/home/aparkin/temp/mymodule/test_mymodule.py", line 18, in <module>
    from StringIO import StringIO
```

But if I ran 2to3 on test_mymodule.py, then that import line should've been reworked to:

```
from io import StringIO
```

And (at worst) the tests should just individually fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for distribute to pick your module up and run in through 2to3, it must be listed in py_modules.  So change that to:

```
py_modules=['mymodule', 'test_mymodule'],
```

Unfortunately this has a side-effect of installing test_mymodule when you install the project, which you probably did not want.  For cases like this I will generally convert the project into a package with a mymodule.tests sub-package.  This way the tests can be "installable" without adding additional clutter.

Comment: What do you mean by mymodule.tests sub-package?

Comment: I mean make a package called "mymodule" and under it create a directory called "tests" and put all your test modules under that, remembering to include an `__init__.py`as well so that tests is a subpackage of mymodule (hence mymodule.tests)